# Render off screen widget in a separate thread Qt

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, qt, qt4

The application I'm working on is made of many C threads communicating together via messages (`0mq`). One of these threads is handling the display and should render off screen a widget in order to communicate its "screenshot" to other threads of the application.

The thing is that in order to paint a widget, you need to place it in a `QApplication` and call the `exec()` method of the `QApplication`, which is essentially a loop. So my thread is then completely stuck and can't communicate with the outside world anymore since it's in the exec() method.

Is there a way I can launch the QApplication in a separate thread and communicate with it so my display thread doesn't get stuck?
Or is there at least a way to do what I want to do with Qt?

Thanks a lot !

Edit: This application will eventually be a Qt Embedded Application

**Update** Basically, my question is :  how to start a QApplication in a separate thread from my C code and communicate with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a separate thread for the QApplication main event loop (exec()) and used 0mq sockets to communicate with it from the rest of my application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you mean by "paint a widget". But be aware: QWidget is a part of GUI and GUI parts should be touched by Main(UI) thread only. It is a rule you can't change. Moreover QApplication works on Main thread only since QApplication is the main part of the GUI itself.
You can post messages to QAppplication by using global `qApp` object(you need to include QApplication for it) and  `sendEvent()` or `postEvent()` methods.

Also I'd suggest you to generate QImage with whatever data you have and propagate it via aforementioned event mechanism to the widget you need. But, obviously, I don't know what you really need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Paint a widget means ...well painting it :D I have to render a widget from events that I receive from other C threads. The ideal thing for me would be to easily communicate between the C code, and the Qt App,with the QApp running on its own, but it doesn't seem there is a simple way to do that at all :/

Comment: You can have dedicated thread for C messages. Inside the thread you'll have some QObject descendant which will use signal\slot mechanism to notify particular widget about new data arrived. And you will paint whatever you need in the widget itself. It is really not complex at all.

Comment: But a widget must be in a Qapplication running in order to be painted , so how could I  launch the QApplication on its own, and connect to it to tell my widget to update?

Comment: You can set appropriate data(in the widget slot) on widget and call `QWidget::update()` method(also in the slot). It will cause `QWidget::paintEvent` virtual function call(by paint event via QApplication dispatch mechanism)

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I don't get how it can work. How can my C thread launch the QApp (the exec() method) on its own, send information to it in order to update the widget, and receive information from the updated widget?

Comment: Read about [signal and slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/signalsandslots.html). Your C thread won't launch anything. QApplication will be in main(). Then you can spawn new thread from  some place(your widget ctor, for example). And from this thread by sending signal you will communicate with Widget. I can't explain the whole Qt world here in comments. You need to dig it yourself also.

Comment: Thank you for telling me about signals and slots.

Comment: It seems to me that your problem has little to do with `Qt` and more to do with the fact that you don't understand `Event-driven programming`. I suggest you do some research to get yourself familiar with that before continuing with your project